# Insert multiline command including variable to a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to create a script to config `rc.local` file. I need to insert multiline command with variable before `exit 0` line.

For example,

- the variable `VARIABLE=31`
- original `rc.local` file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# blah blah...

exit 0
```

- desired `rc.local` after executing `setup.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# blah blah...

if [ `gpio read 31` = 1 ]; then  # this 31 is the value of VARIABLE
  do_something
fi

exit 0
```

---

This is my attemption:

```bsh
VARIABLE=31
sed "/^exit 0/i \
if [ \`gpio read $VARIABLE\` = 1 ]; then \
  do_something \
fi" -i rc.local
```

But the result `rc.local` is

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# blah blah...

if [ `gpio read 31` = 1 ]; then do_something fi
exit 0
```

I cannot get the linebreak.

And if I use `\n`, it errors with

```
unknown command: `m'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using double-quotes (`"`) for your `sed` command.

The backslashes get thus interpreted *and consumed* by the *running* shell, just like it does for those preceding the backticks, which I believe you used precisely to make your running shell *not* interpret those backticks itself.

To solve this, you need to use two backslashes (`\\`) *only* for the backslashes preceding the newlines.